# How to hide and show data depending on the data filter?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have some projects which I want to filter using the **data-filter** property.
I have three buttons to filter different type of projects and a list containing all projects.

```
 <div class="project-categories d-flex position-relative">
     <a data-filter="all" >All</a>
     <a  data-filter="backend" >Backend</a>
     <a  data-filter="frontend" >Frontend</a>
 </div>
 <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center">
     <div class="project-list row-inner">  
        <div class="project isActive" data-filter="frontend backend"></div>    
        <div class="project isActive" data-filter="backend"></div>    
     </div>
 </div>
```

How can I filter through the projects depending on its data filter property?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't really need data attributes for this logic. I think you want to rewrite it from some legacy project. Also, I wouldn't recommend you to use `a` tag without `href` attribute, since it's not semantic.
One way you could do it is to create a computed property, that will listen to your filter array. For example:

```
<div class="project-categories d-flex position-relative">
  <span @click="filterArray.push(all)" >All</span>
  <span  @click="filterArray.push(backend)" >Backend</span>
  <span  @click="filterArray.push(frontend)" >Frontend</span>
</div>
<div class="row d-flex justify-content-center">
 <div class="project-list row-inner">  
    <div class="project isActive" data-filter="frontend backend"> 
     {{ projects }} 
    </div>      
 </div>
</div>

  data() {
    return { 
     filterArray = []
    }
  }
  computed: {
    projects() {
     if(this.filterArray.length) {
      ... your logic
     }
   }
  }
```

Comment: That makes sense. I saw it in a tutorial [here](https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/all-you-need-to-know-about-the-html5-data-attribute--webdesign-9642) where they defined own data properties.

Comment: Would the approach promoted in the tutorial be totally wrong?

Comment: this approach is more in JQuery fashion. Although, I think you can achieve CSS only filtering with this approach, but why:)